# What does an underscore concatenated to a class name mean?

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I was reading the ["Dynamic, typesafe queries in JPA 2.0"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/) article and stumbled upon this example:

```
EntityManager em = ...
CriteriaBuilder qb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Person> c = qb.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> p = c.from(Person.class);
Predicate condition = qb.gt(p.get(Person_.age), 20);
//                                     ^^ --- this one
c.where(condition);
TypedQuery<Person> q = em.createQuery(c); 
List<Person> result = q.getResultList();
```

I was wondering, what exactly does the underscore here mean?

Since an underscore it is a valid part of a classname I don't understand why this can be used in JPA. 
I checked this with an existing entity in my code and of course my class couldn't be resolved as `ClassName_`

Comment: You can also ask this question of that article author :)

Comment: And if stacker had done that, I would have never found this question and answer and I'd still be looking.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

That is the [metamodel](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/#N102F2) for the persistance. It is how you can do type safe JPA queries in Java. It allows queries to staticly check your queries because class`Bar_` describes your JPA `Bar`. In HQL, you can easily mistype a query and not know it until it is run.

So technically, the `_` does not mean anything, but it is the convention used by JPA to name a metamodel class of a JPA persistent model class. `Model_` is the metamodel of `Model`, and it provides the names of the queryable fields and their types.

Comment: Do I have to include another maven dependecy? The `Bar_`must be known by the compiler which isn't currently the case.

Comment: Well you could write the metamodel by hand, have it generated and then copy over the files by hand, or incorporate it into your Maven build. I found [this Maven plugin](http://janistoolbox.typepad.com/blog/2010/03/java-persistency-api-20-jpa-hibernate-jpa-metamodel-generator-maven-1.html) that might do the job.

Comment: @stacker did that plug-in help? If so I'll add it to the answer itself.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but I decided not to depend on further libraries. I will continue using native queries ;-)

Comment: Following dependency will generate **Person_** classe. It is very useful while writing predicates.  

`<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    </dependency>`

Comment: "import javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute;"  from here (I think) : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api

Answer (score 3):

I found this way to declare the metamodel in this [article](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-four-jpa-criteria-queries/).

```
/**
 * A  meta model class used to create type safe queries from person
 * information.
 * @author Petri Kainulainen
 */
@StaticMetamodel(Person.class)
public class Person_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Person, String> lastName;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was referring to by doing it by hand. :) I'm pretty sure that as long as you have they `@StaticMetamodel` annotation you can name the actual class whatever you like.