# In android programming, what's the meaning of a class name concatenated an underscore?

Tags: java, android

```java
public class VideoFragment extends Fragment implements CacheListener {
       ...
 public static Fragment build(String url, String cachePath) {
        return VideoFragment_.builder()
                .url(url)
                .cachePath(cachePath)
                .build();
    }
      ...
}
```

I searched a lot, but still have no idea about "VideoFragment_"?
Can someone give me some main points?

Comment: In fact, I'm studying [this android project](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/danikula/videocache/sample/VideoFragment.java) in github

Comment: Huh, [Today I Learned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9379553/1790644). Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does an underscore concatenated to a class name mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379536/what-does-an-underscore-concatenated-to-a-class-name-mean)

Comment: Before I post my question, I've read these above questions; but they are very different. People cannot solver problem by reference them. Different contexts and different answer.  laalto gave a great answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Underscore has no special meaning in Java or in Android. It's just a part of the name.

You'll need to ask the original author of the code what was the intent of such naming.

---

From comments:

> In fact, I'm studying [this android project](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/danikula/videocache/sample/VideoFragment.java) in github

This is relevant information to the question. The project is using [android-annotations enhanced fragments](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance-Fragments) where:

> AndroidAnnotations will generate a fragment subclass with a trailing underscore, e.g. `MyFragment_`. You should **use the generated subclass** in your xml layouts and when creating new instance fragments

so it's a feature of the annotation processor.

Comment: While this is a single occurrence in the class, and even can't find it in parent class.

Comment: I sent mail to ask the author, perhaps he is too  busy to reply.